# Sum of variables from multiple dataset

Tags: r, append, subset, sas-macro

I have 4 dataset `finance1`, `finance2`, `finance3`, `finance4`
each dataset have colnames : `'CIF'`, `'X'`, `'Y'`.

```
finance1 <- data.frame(CIF = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
                       X= c(500000, 1500000, 2000000),
                       Y= c(250000, 500000, 1500000))

finance2 <- data.frame(CIF = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A5'),
                       X= c(500000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000),
                       Y= c(250000, 500000, 1500000, 2000000))

finance3 <- data.frame(CIF = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A9'),
                       X= c(500000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000, 3000000),
                       Y= c(250000, 500000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000))
```

How can I get

```
finance1 <- data.frame(CIF = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'),
                       X= c(500000, 1500000, 2000000),
                       Y= c(250000, 500000, 1500000),
                       sum_X = c(1500000, 4500000, 6000000),
                       sum_Y = c(500000, 1000000, 3000000))
```

where `sum_X = finance2$X +finance3$X` #based on the same CIF only
where `sum_Y = finance2$Y +finance3$Y` #based on the same CIF only

And then repetitive for the next dataset:

```
finance2 <- data.frame(CIF = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A5'),
                       X= c(500000, 1500000, 2000000, 2500000),
                       Y= c(250000, 500000, 1500000, 2000000))
                       sum_X = c(500000, 1500000, 2000000, .),
                       sum_Y = c(250000, 500000, 1500000, .))
```

where `sum_X = finance3$X` #based on the CIF and because the last dataset is finance3
where `sum_Y = finance3$Y` #based on the CIF and because the last dataset is finance3

How do I write this in R that I have done it with macro SAS, that use data and subset data. and the append. But I really confuse to do it in R with multiple columns data frame.

Comment: You can't have a dataset with different number of rows between columns. How do you handle the sum of two unequal vectors?

Comment: i want sum just only same CIF

Comment: Then, why is sum_Y of finance1 `sum_Y = c(500000, 1000000, 3000000, 4000000, 5000000)`? it should be only three values

Comment: Sorry for that, I have edited for that

Answer (score 0):

You can sum the column `X` only for rows where `CIF` is `c("A1", "A2", "A3")`:

```r
cols = c("A1", "A2", "A3")
finance1$sum_X <- 
  finance2[finance2$CIF %in% cols, ]$X + finance3[finance3$CIF %in% cols, ]$X
```

```r
  CIF       X       Y sum_X
1  A1  500000  250000 1e+06
2  A2 1500000  500000 3e+06
3  A3 2000000 1500000 4e+06
```

---

Now if you wanna make this more dynamic, you can use `sapply`:

```r
finance1[paste0("sum_", c("X", "Y"))] <- 
  sapply(c("X", "Y"), function(x) finance2[finance2$CIF %in% cols, x] + finance3[finance3$CIF %in% cols, x])
```

```r
  CIF       X       Y sum_X sum_Y
1  A1  500000  250000 1e+06 5e+05
2  A2 1500000  500000 3e+06 1e+06
3  A3 2000000 1500000 4e+06 3e+06
```